# Radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}z^n $ and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{n}}z^n $ is the same .

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that an $a_{n} \neq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} $. If $R$ is the radius of convergence of both the series : $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}z^n \ \text{ and } \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{n}}z^n$$
Then show that $R=1$.
One way to prove this is by contradiction Suppose that $R > 1$ then :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} \ \text{ and } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{n}} \ \text{ converges }$$
which implies that :
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n} = 0 , \  \lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{a_{n}}=0 }$$which gives contradiction the same argument will fail for $R < 1$.
The second way is let $$
 \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}=\ell=\frac{1}{R}$$
And $$\frac{1}{\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}}=\frac{1}{\ell'}$$
So $\ell' \leq \ell $ and $\frac{1}{\ell'}=\ell$ if $\ell'<\ell<1 \ $then $\frac{1}{\ell'}>1>\ell$contradiction similarly for the other cases .

The counter example is: $a_{n}= 2^n  $ if $n$ is even and $\frac{1}{2^n} $ if $n$ is odd.

Note : this is not my idea .

Comment: I know the question is seems to be easy but I think the question is wrong because I have a counter example .

Comment: Then show off the said counter-example.

Comment: How does the same argument fail for $R<1$?

Comment: In your second method, you only showed that $l\geq1$, hence $R\leq1$. What do you mean by _similarly for the other cases?_ it seems that what you think is _similar for the other cases_ isn't! just write them down.

Comment: Use the fact that the radius of convergence $R$ of a power series $\sum c_n z^n$ is given by $R = \sup \{ r \geq 0 | \text{ the sequence } | c_n r^n | \text{ is bounded} \}$. You should be able to see that the assumption $R \ne 1$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: @Dilemian: how does that give any contradictions? You'll get a clear contradiction with $R>1$; but certainly not with $R\leq1$.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Oh, I realized that there is a counterexample. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The Cauchy-Hadamard formula only yields $R \leqslant 1$ under the given conditions, for

$$\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n\rvert} \geqslant \liminf_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n\rvert} = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{1/\lvert a_n\rvert}} = \frac{1}{1/R} = R.$$

Your example shows that $R < 1$ is indeed possible.

The common radius of convergence would have to be $1$ if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\lvert a_n\rvert}{\lvert a_{n+1}\rvert}$ exists.